# Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'Le' before initialization in production environment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

when I tried to access the production website, the console show error log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'Le' before initialization
    xh https://zj.example.top/assets/vendor-3243b884.js:26
    <anonymous> https://zj.example.top/assets/vendor-3243b884.js:26
vendor-3243b884.js:26:52
    xh https://zj.poemhub.top/assets/vendor-3243b884.js:26
    <anonymous> https://zj.example.top/assets/vendor-3243b884.js:26
```

I traced into the verdor js, and found the error come from `react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js`, I am using react + typescript and using vite to compile and split the chunks. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? BTW, this code work fine in develop environment.